# Gdm uninstallation fails (“pre-removal script returned error”)

Tags: debian, package-management, apt, dpkg, gdm3

I installed gdm on my vps and now I want to remove it but get this error:

```
root@server2:/etc/init.d# apt-get remove gdm3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gdm3
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
After this operation, 7066 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 119416 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gdm3 ...
invoke-rc.d: initscript gdm3, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing gdm3 (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
configured to not write apport reports
                                      invoke-rc.d: initscript gdm3, action "reload" failed.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gdm3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@server2:/etc/init.d#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when removing the package, some cleanup scripts are run. it seems like one of these fails (namely `/etc/init.d/gdm3`), rendering the un-installation incomplete.

the proper way to fix this, is by checking why the script fails.
try running

```
/etc/init.d/gdm3 stop
```

manually, and see why it fails. fix the underlying error, then try to uninstall again.

### an ugly hack

if the underlying problem is unfixable (by you), you might have more luck with the following simple fix:

first make sure that `gdm3` is no longer running (as a last ressort you might kill it).

then add the line `exit 0` to the beginning of the `/etc/init.d/gdm3` file (somewhen after the shebang, but before the script actually does anything; e.g. line#2).
this will practically disable the script and make it pretend to always succeed.

finally re-run the uninstallation.

*NOTE*: this is a really ugly hack, as it circumvents any cleanup the init.d-script might need to perform. be warned.

Comment: I did /etc/init.d/gdm3 stop with no luck but your ugly hack worked